# Running a multi project Maven-built webapp on Heroku?

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, cloudbees

I'm migrating my multi project Java webapp from `Cloudbees` to `Heroku`.  I have one main webapp that depends on 3 other library projects that I have written (also *Maven+Java*).  On `Cloudbees` this was simple, you just build everything through *Jenkins*, the JARs get poked into their Maven repos then the main webapp gets built taking its dependencies from that `Maven` repos.

However, I can't for the life of me find a way of doing this on Heroku without doing something horrendous like this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

By doing so it would mean that every time I changed a library I would have to remember to deploy the built JAR to the main webapp project and push this to Git, somewhat defeating the point of using Maven!

I understand that the way to deploy your webapp on Heroku is essentially by doing a git push to their repo, but how can I tell heroku at the other end to find my library dependencies without having to bundle them in the main webapp like this article suggests?

I would assume that there is some way to set up a private maven repos on your heroku account but I can't find anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use a private Maven repository, and then add the config for that repo in the `settings.xml` of your main project. [This article on using a custom `settings.xml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml) describes how to do that.

There are some services that host private Maven repos for you, such as [JFrog](http://www.jfrog.com/). But I've even read of people [using Github to host a Maven repo](http://www.sigil.org/coding/hosting-a-private-maven-repository-using-github/), too.